# Send email to resubscribe customer?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

Is there any option to send an email to customers who resubscribe after they unsubscribed in marketing cloud?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do this? If someone unsubscribes then they have indicated that **THEY DO NOT WANT TO RECEIVE ANY EMAIL FROM YOU**.

You can still send them transactional messages, but sending them any more commercial messages would violate major regulatory requirements (CAN-SPAM, EU Data Directive, incoming GDPR).

Also , when they unsubscribe, the system will not let you send emails to them as their status in the AllSubscribersList would change to `unsubscribe`.